# "Invalid provider for the NgModule" when using AoT

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

Without AoT everything works fine. But after switching loaders, I am getting this error and have no clue how to fix it, or what exactly is wrong.

> Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule in
>   /xxx/src/app/app.module.ts' - only instances of Provider and Type are
>   allowed, got: [LoggerService in
>   /xxx/src/app/services/logger-service.service.ts, LocalStorageService
>   in
>   /xxx/node_modules/angular-2-local-storage/dist/local-storage.service.d.ts,
>   WindowService in /xxx/src/app/services/window.service.ts, ?null?, ...]

Related code from `AppModule`:

```
import CustomHttp from './services/custom-http.service';

...

@NgModule({

...

  providers: [
    LocalStorageService,
    WindowService,
    AuthService,
    LoggerService,
    CustomHttp,
    AuthTokenStore,
    AuthService,
    SchemaValidator,
    AuthInterceptor,
    DataService,
    ErrorHelper,
    FileUpload,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: LoggingErrorHandler},
    NonAngularDialogsHelper,
    ConfirmationService,
    SearchHelper,
    FormHelper,
    DebugHelper,
    PuxApplication,
    StoreUtils,
    TranslationHelper,
    MessagesService,
    CustomValidatorsService,
    GeolocationService,
    SavedSearchesService,
    LoggedInfoService,
    BeTranslate,
    CountryHelper,
    SuggestionGenerators,
    PrimeNgHelper,
    UrlHelper,
    DocumentClickService,
    NavigationHelper,
    BeErrorsInterceptor,
    DocumentService,
    ScrollHelper,
    LinkDialogHelper,
    HtmlUtilsService,
    RouterHelperService,
    StripeService,
    VatExamplesService,
    ContactInfoHelper,
    WizardHelper,
    PasswordChangingPagesHelper,
    LandingPageHelper,
    TrackingEventsHelper,
    RfoHelper,
    ReactiveFormsHelper,
    LiveChatService,

    CounterActions
  ]

...
```

Snippets from `CustomHttp`:

```
...

@Injectable()
export default class CustomHttp {

...

  constructor(private http: Http,
              loggerService: LoggerService) {
    this.logger = loggerService.createLogger('CustomHttp');
  }

...
```

Edit 1: Added whole providers array as requested.

Comment: Could you post your whole array of providers, and check if all of the providers have the `@Injectable` decorator ?

Comment: @trichetriche I have updated the question with complete providers array as requested and checked, that all our providers have `@Injectable()` annotation. I wish AoT was just as easy as switching some plugin option, this is just too much unexplained foggy dark magic for me.

Comment: make sure you are not adding anything which is not included in your logger or window service, can you post your logger service code

Comment: So all of your classes provided into `providers` have the `@Injectable` annotation ? even `CounterActions`, the last one ? And why are you providing a replacement for `ErrorHandler` ? What happens when you simply provide the `LoggingErrorHandler` ?

Comment: Yes, all of them, even the last one. It's for sending errors to backend - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007743/9160022. Tried commenting it out, but the compilation error is same. It doesn't seem to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AoT compiler is not very clever. Turns out that it can't handle default imports for some reason...

Not working:

```
import CustomHttp from './services/custom-http.service';
```

Working:

```
import { CustomHttp } from './services/custom-http.service';
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently this is a known issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11402

Comment: How do I get around this problem when the 3rd party library only provides the class as a default export? Ex: https://github.com/CapnMarius/EventAggregator/blob/master/src/index.ts. EventAggregator is only exported as default.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have included duplicate export statements for some services in service's index.ts file. Finally it works after removing one.

(you can use Excel to find out duplicates. :-) )

got from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42366630/2315972)

```
.....
export * from './custom-message.service';
export * from './department.service';
export * from './custom-message.service'; // duplicated, remove this
.......
```